# Postgres - Dynamically referencing columns from record variable

Tags: postgresql, variables, record

I'm having trouble referencing record variable type columns dynamically. I found loads of tricks online, but with regards to triggers mostly and I really hope the answer isn't "it can't be done"... I've got a very specific and simple need, see my example code below;

First I have an array containing a list of column names called "**lCols**". I loop through a record variable to traverse my data, replacing values in a paragraph which exactly match my column names.

```
DECLARE lTotalRec RECORD;        
DECLARE lSQL text;
DECLARE lCols varchar[];

p_paragraph:= 'I am [names] and my surname is [surname]';

lSQL := 
    'select         
        p.names,
        p.surname
    from 
        person p
    ';

FOR lTotalRec IN
    execute lSQL        
LOOP
    -- Loop through the already created array of columns to replace the values in the paragraph
    FOREACH lVal IN ARRAY lCols
    LOOP
        p_paragraph := replace(p_paragraph,'[' || lVal || ']',lTotalRec.lVal); -- This is where my problem is, because lVal is not a column of lTotalRec directly like this      
    END LOOP;

    RETURN NEXT;
END LOOP;
```

My return value is the paragraph amended for each record in **"lTotalRec"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert your `record` to a `json` value using the `row_to_json()` function. Once in this format, you can extract columns by name, using the `->` and `->>` operators.

In Postgres 9.4 and up, you can also make use of the more efficient `jsonb` type.

```
DECLARE lJsonRec jsonb;

...

FOR lTotalRec IN
    execute lSQL        
LOOP
    lJsonRec := row_to_json(lTotalRec)::jsonb;
    FOREACH lVal IN ARRAY lCols
    LOOP
        p_paragraph := replace(p_paragraph, '[' || lVal || ']', lJsonRec->>lVal);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN NEXT;
END LOOP;
```

See the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) for more details.

Comment: Works like a charm, I was on the right track but just didn't get to the point where you can use JSON inline like this, great answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a row to JSON using [`row_to_json()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), and then retrieve the column names using `json_object_keys()`.

Here's an example:

```
drop table if exists TestTable;

create table TestTable (col1 text, col2 text);
insert into TestTable values ('a1', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2');

do $$declare
    sql text;
    rec jsonb;
    col text;
    val text;
begin
sql := 'select row_to_json(row) from (select * from TestTable) row';
for rec in execute sql loop
    for col in select * from jsonb_object_keys(rec) loop
        val := rec->>col;
        raise notice 'col=% val=%', col, val;
    end loop;
end loop;
end$$;
```

This prints:

```
NOTICE:  col=col1 val=a1
NOTICE:  col=col2 val=b1
NOTICE:  col=col1 val=a2
NOTICE:  col=col2 val=b2
DO
```